# How to suppress mypy error: "some/path/to/module" shadows library module "module"

Tags: python, mypy, error-suppression, skulpt

I'm well aware that normally you wouldn't want to suppress this error, but my case is special. I'm "poly-filling" [skulpt](https://skulpt.org) with some modules that it lacks in stdlib ("typing" and "typing_extensions" to be exact). How can I suppress this error? Preferably where:

1. Suppression only applies for specific files.
2. Mypy doesn't use type-hins/annotations from my local file, but rather from where it would take them if it didn't exist...
3. Mypy still runs on that specified file.

Comment: Does [`--shadow-file`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html?highlight=shadow#cmdoption-mypy-shadow-file) do what you want? Because this doesn't seem like something you can just ignore - `mypy --show-error-codes sys.py` shows a generic error message, not a validation error.

Comment: @l0b0 Sadly no matter what I try, it doesn't go away. Probably mypy checks the file names before that step. Even if it would work, what second path should be for ``--shadow-file``? Maybe I did something wrong while testing, but I don't know how to approach this...